# Jquery selector to find all inputs that don't have an specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a jQuery selector to find all inputs that don't have the class "clear" to make their values uppercase.

Currently I have this code:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    $("input[type=text]").val(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("clear")) {
            return this.value.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            return this.value;
        }
    });

    $("input[type=text].lower").val(function () {
        return this.value.toLowerCase();
    });
});
```

This code is working well, but if I could make it using only the selector, I can skip the if/else code. I've searched for this selector, but without success.

Any idea?

Final Code

My final code looks like this:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    $("input[type=text]").not(".clear").not(".lower").val(function () {
        return this.value.toUpperCase();
    });

    $("input[type=text].lower").val(function () {
        return this.value.toLowerCase();
    });
});
```

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: The way you're currently doing it is actually more efficient. I'd even move the .lower handling into the first if else.

Comment: @KevinB I can't do this because I have three states: everything to lower, everything to upper or everything as user inputted.

Comment: You can have an if elseif else, or simply return from each if such as Travis J's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$("input[type=text]").not("YOUR_CLASS").val(function () {
        return this.value.toUpperCase();
    });
```

Comment: This is the better way. From the jQeury API: "The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not() selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice."

Comment: Can I do something like this: `$("input[type=text]").not("clear").not("lower").val(function () {...` I think my code will get better with this.

Comment: @WellingtonZanelli Yes you can use. :)

Answer (score 7):

Use [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$("input[type=text]:not(.clear)").val(function () {
    return this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: And the lower case clause?

Answer (score 2):

Take the original selector and then keep your condition statements. Just do them both at once. Note that returning this.value is redundant so it is removed here.

```
$("input[type=text]").val(function () {
    var $t = $(this);
    if ( $t.hasClass("lower") ) return this.value.toLowerCase();
    if ( !$t.hasClass("clear") ) return this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery pseudo-selector `:not` -

```
$("input[type=text]:not(.clear)")
```

[Here](http://jqapi.com/#p=not-selector) is some documentation on it

EDIT: Use the .not() function instead of :not when you can - [it performs better](http://jsperf.com/comparing-jquery-s-filter-vs-not)